# Why we use Strategy Facade in Java projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

What is the use of Strategy Facade in Java projects?
Please help on this.

Comment: is this you home work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (also known as the policy pattern) is a software design pattern, whereby an algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime.
Get *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*, it changed my mind (and I learnt a lot!)

Answer (score 2):

[Its a design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code

[image]

Comment: yaaa.But can u provide me any example.so that I can understand it better way.

Comment: Have you even opend the link I provided ?? There is a simple example and diagram also there.